# Хранение авторизации Vkontakte в android приложении

Tags: android, android-sdk, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Необходима авторизация через Вконтакте в приложении. Как лучше всего хранить полученный токен авторизации в приложении и как подставлять его автоматически если он еще не устарел? SharedPreference и SQLite небезопасны. Есть возможность хранить во внешней MySQL базе.

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под безопасностью?

Comment: Что никто не сможет получить token не имея доступа. Оказывается VK SDK  сам где-то его запоминает, есть VKAccessToken.curenttoken(). Пожалуй положусь на них:) это же в их интересах хранить секурно.

Answer (score 3):

SharedPreference с MODE_PRIVATE http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE будет доступно только для текущего приложения

Если это кажется недостаточно безопасным можно использовать реализацию с шифрованием https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences

Comment: Про шифрование очень интересно. Как бы привязать туда сертификат которым подписываешь APK при релизе? Нет идей?

Comment: Мне кажется релизный ключ не стоит добавлять в проект, он должен хранится где-то локально